# Migrating Shipping Extension for Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento2

I am trying to migrate a custom magento 1.9 extension to magento 2.2. I have done a lot of searching and can't find information on the use case I'm trying to migrate. I originally followed [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/#comments-create-custom-shipping-methods-magento) for the 1.9 extension. I understand there is a tool to help port extensions, but I am trying to do this manually as I couldn't get that tool to function for me.

The custom shipping extension would run each time the shopping cart was updated to calculate a custom shipping rate. The goal is to recreate this extension in magento 2.2 such that each time the shopping cart is opened or updated it will run and calculate a shipping cost which will then propagate through the checkout process.

Below is an overview of the magento 1.9 extension. Any advice on how to translate this to magento 2.2?

**/app/etc/modules/Extensions_Shipper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Extensions_Shipper>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </Extensions_Shipper>
</modules>
```

**/app/code/local/Extensions/Shipper/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Extensions_Shipper>
        <module>0.0.1</module>
    </Extensions_Shipper>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <extensions_shipper>
            <class>Extensions_Shipper_Model</class>
        </extensions_shipper>
    </models>
</global>
<default>
    <carriers>
        <extensions_shipper>
            <active>1</active>
            <model>extensions_shipper/carrier</model>
            <title>Shipping Options</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
        </extensions_shipper>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

**/app/code/local/Extensions/Shipper/Model/Carrier.php**

```
<?php
class Extensions_Shipper_Model_Carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        //Are there magento 2.2 equivalence for the following?
        $addressInfo = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $currentItem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items[$itemsArray[$i]]->getProduct()->getId());
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('some text');
        //$result = some calculations for shipping rate
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event observer on the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event to execute the logic to update the shipping costs.

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //Observer initialization code...
    //You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    //Observer execution code...
  }
}
```

Subscribe to the event in `events.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="my_module_event_before">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="my_module_event_after">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\AnotherObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

---

See Magento docs on events and observers: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

For a list of all Magento 2.2 events, see: https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/